# Converting a String to a String[] yields different results when used in variable definition or as function parameters

Tags: arrays, string, groovy

I am trying to implement a small function in Groovy, taking a array of String as an input and printing it in a YAML format.

It seems Groovy is converting String variables to String[] in different ways whether it's occurring at variable definition or in the definition of a function parameter.

This curious behavior is shown with the following code snippet:

```groovy
// #1
println '#1'
def h = 'one'
println h.class
String[] a = h
println a.class
println a.length
println a

// #2
println '#2'
String f(String[] param) {
  println param.class
  println param.length
  println param
}
f(h)
```

Running with Groovy 2.4.16:

```
#1
class java.lang.String
class [Ljava.lang.String;
3
[o, n, e]
#2
class [Ljava.lang.String;
1
[one]
```

I have searched the Groovy spec and didn't find anything explaining this behavior.

Does anybody have an explanation why:

- passing a String to a String[] variable in a variable definition splits the String to its individual characters,
- whereas passing a String to a function expecting a String[] parameter will create an array of size 1 with the given string?

I would have expected both situation to yield to the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second part is not coercing/casting at all; you are using variadic
arguments like in Java (the language), which of the underlying JVM has
no concept of and always uses arrays.

The first part would be roughly [the cast to array via
list](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/lang/String.html#asType(java.lang.Class))

Comment: Thanks! With that hint I could find it in the doc as well. I’ll link to the Groovy documentation for reference: https://groovy-lang.org/objectorientation.html#_varargs